# Flash Rust Under Wok Seasoning

Tags: seasoning, pot, carbon-steel

This was my first attempt seasoning a piece of cookware. I used the following approach:

- I scrubbed the wok down on both sides with a scouring pad and dish
  soap.
- I then heated the wok up and moved the wok around the flame until it
  was blue all over.
- I then took the wok off the heat, cooled it down with a bit of water,
  and gave it another scrubbing with the scouring pad and dish soap.
- I then wiped the wok off with a kitchen towel. I left it for maybe a
  couple of minutes, and when I came back I noticed rust already
  developing on the wok. I believe this was flash rust.
- I then heated the wok up on the flame to dry it. I took the wok off
  the flame and let it cool.
- I then put some oil in the wok and heated it on the flame until it
  was smoking to season it.

After all that, I think I have some flash rust under the seasoning. Please see the red circle in the picture. Is this rust, and does this mean I need to strip it and re-season it? If so, how could I avoid the having this happen again?

[image]

Comment: There are a myriad duplicate questions on here regarding seasoning. Looking at your pictures, you barely got one thin layer yet. Scrub it off & start over. Use your oven. A burner ring cannot get enough heat to the top edges of a wok to season properly.

Comment: Also, DON"T use a scouring pad!  You scratched the heck out of the wok.  Not sure it'll recover from that.

Comment: @FuzzyChef What do you recommend to use?  When you say it won't recover, do you mean the current seasoning would need to be redone, or the entire wok wouldn't recover for some reason?

Comment: I mean you may have wrecked the wok, unless you want to polish the entire surface using fine-grit sandpaper followed by a butter and steel polishing compound.  You really scratched it up.  It's possible with hard enough seasoning you'll be able to use it normally, but it's also possible you won't.

Comment: Never, ever use scouring pads on anything softer than stainless steel.

Comment: @FuzzyChef Oh, I see.  Yes, I did really scour it and there are a fair amount of scratches on the surface.  In the picture, that circled "rust" (I believe it's rust, but not sure), doesn't come off when wiped.  Do you think I should re-season like the previous commenter suggested, or should I simply use it to cook and build up seasoning? Thanks!

Comment: How certain are you that the stuff on the rim is rust?  It looks more like congealed (but not polymerized) oil to me.

Comment: @FuzzyChef I'd say it's more likely rust than not, but I'm not sure and I'm clearly not an expert.  I believe it's rust, because after I stripped the wok of its protective coating and gave it a quick wash with soap and water it started to rust almost immediately.  I figured the rust would come off in the seasoning process, so I dried it on the flame and started with the first coat of oil... I'm thinking it's rust under oil, but I'm not quite sure.

Comment: Heating does not remove rust.

Comment: that does not look like rust, that looks like the metal getting heat treated, or another layer of seasoning. (It looks gold)  
-----
btw unless your wok has a hole in it, or is worn so thin as to be very close to it, you definitely have not ruined it. just season over it, it will fill in the gaps with time.  
-----
btw there are many types of steel at many different hardnesses and tempers. being stainless is unrelated to that

Comment: @FuzzyChef there are steel scouring pads and plastic ones.  Are you referring to both, or just steel?  The same question could also be applied to the OP.

Comment: Also, I wouldn't cool with water at any stage (except possibly by holding it upside down and pouring water over the outside).  My cheap carbon steel wok rusts easily when hot and wet

Comment: On a wok, you shouldn't use any scrubby harder than bamboo.  So: plastic net scrubby OK, "nonstick safe" scrubby OK, bamboo brush OK, sisal brush OK, steel wool NO, green abrasive scrubbers NO.  Also, oil & salt is OK but not Barkeeper's Friend.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell with those lighting conditions, but no it does not look like rust.
It looks like either another layer of (partial) seasoning or the bare steel that has been partially heat tempered: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/89/Tempering_standards_used_in_blacksmithing.JPG

Rust is a dark burgundy color and red rust in particular will wipe off with a paper towel.
If this happens to be red rust, you can just clean it off with soap and a sponge and season over it.